# zsh: killed adb on macOS

Tags: android, macos, adb

I'm trying to resolve an issue related to adb. Whenever I type "adb" and associated commands (`adb kill-server`, `adb devices`, etc.) I get this output:

`zsh: killed   adb`

In other similar questions on StackOverflow, the issue has typically been the path. However, my path includes the correct file paths, for reference here is my complete PATH:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin
/opt/homebrew/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/share/dotnet
~/.dotnet/tools
/Library/Apple/usr/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
/Users/${USER}/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
/Users/${USER}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
/Users/${USER}/.dotnet/tools
/Users/${USER}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
```

So, a bit confused here. The only reason platform-tools is in there twice is because I've tried removing and adding it a few times (and then restarting the terminal), as that's what most other StackOverflow answers suggested.

And anything I try to run involving Android fails. It doesn't ever say command not found, just `zsh: killed`. I know that my adb is installed in Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb, and warning messages tell me that's where it is too. However, when I try to simply run `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb`, I get the same `zsh: killed` error, which makes me think there's something wrong with my adb and not the path.

For what it's worth, I'm on macOS Ventura 13.0 and I have an Apple M1 chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by opening Activity Monitor, finding the 'adb' process and force quitting it through the Activity Monitor GUI. Not sure what was wrong but this solved my problem.